# One GameObject always hits the other first

Tags: unity-game-engine

Firstly, I apologize for throwing so much code up here. While I think maybe 5% of it is important to this question, I'd rather leave no stone unturned.

I'm relatively new to Unity and I'm prototyping a game where you can place an army vs another player and they fight it out on a 2D plane similar to [Mage and Monsters](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1950440/Mage_and_Monsters/).

I'm testing with two units, one on each team, and seemingly no matter what, team 2 always hits first and always wins the fight - there is no variability. While I intend to add crit chance and whatnot, if Team2 always hits first, they are at an inherent advantage.

The units share the exact same stats.

I tried to do everything I could to ensure that both units are initialized at the same time and they do not start until that is the case. However, no matter what Unit2 (of Team2) always starts first, hits first, and therefore wins.

Here is my BaseUnit code which was [this repo](https://github.com/okgamesyt/ok-auto-battle):

```
public class BaseUnit : MonoBehaviour
{

    public UnitData unitData;

    public int baseHealth;
    public int health;
    public int level;
    
    public int damage;
    public float range;
    public float attackSpeed;
    public float movementSpeed;

    public Team myTeam;
    public bool IsReady = false;
    public bool IsPlaying = false;
    protected BaseUnit currentTarget = null;

    protected bool HasEnemy => currentTarget != null;
    protected bool IsInRange => currentTarget != null && Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, currentTarget.transform.position) <= range;
    
    protected bool dead = false;
    protected bool canAttack = true;
    protected float waitBetweenAttack;

    void Start()
    {
        baseHealth = unitData.health;
        health = baseHealth;
        level = unitData.level;

        damage = unitData.damage;
        range = unitData.range;
        attackSpeed = unitData.attackSpeed;
        movementSpeed = unitData.movementSpeed;

        UnitManager.Instance.OnRoundStart += OnRoundStart;
        UnitManager.Instance.OnRoundEnd += OnRoundEnd;
        UnitManager.Instance.OnUnitDied += OnUnitDied;

        IsReady = true;
    }

    protected virtual void OnRoundStart() {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " OnRoundStart!");
        IsPlaying = true;
    }
    protected virtual void OnRoundEnd() { }
    protected virtual void OnUnitDied(BaseUnit diedUnit) { }

    protected void FindTarget() {
        var allEnemies = UnitManager.Instance.GetUnitsAgainst(myTeam);
        float minDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
        BaseUnit entity = null;
        foreach (BaseUnit be in allEnemies) {
            if (Vector3.Distance(be.transform.position, this.transform.position) <= minDistance) {
                minDistance = Vector3.Distance(be.transform.position, this.transform.position);
                entity = be;
            }
        }

        currentTarget = entity;
    }

    protected void GetInRange() {
        if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(currentTarget.transform.position, this.transform.position)) > range) {
            var step = movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.transform.position, currentTarget.transform.position, step);
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int incomingDamage) { // Maybe add damage type eventually
        baseHealth -= incomingDamage;

        if (baseHealth <= 0 && !dead) {
            dead = true;
            UnitManager.Instance.UnitDead(this);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Attack() {
        if (!canAttack) {
            return;
        }

        waitBetweenAttack = 1 / attackSpeed;
        StartCoroutine(WaitCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator WaitCoroutine()
    {
        canAttack = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitBetweenAttack);
        canAttack = true;
    }
}
```

My MeleeUnit which is the class each of the units use:

```
public class MeleeUnit : BaseUnit
{
    protected override void OnRoundStart() {
        base.OnRoundStart();

        Debug.Log("Melee OnRoundStart for " + gameObject.name);

        FindTarget();
    }

    public void Update() {
        if (!IsPlaying) {
            return;
        }
        
        if (!HasEnemy) {
            FindTarget();
        }

        if (IsInRange) {
            if (canAttack) {
                Attack();
                currentTarget.TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        }
    }

    public void FixedUpdate() {
        if (!IsPlaying) {
            return;
        }

        if (!HasEnemy) {
            return;
        }

        if (!IsInRange) {
            GetInRange();
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the UnitManager class which kicks things off:

```
public class UnitManager : Manager<UnitManager>
{

    private string teamOneTag = "Team1";
    private string teamTwoTag = "Team2";

    public List<BaseUnit> teamOne = new List<BaseUnit>();
    public List<BaseUnit> teamTwo = new List<BaseUnit>();

    public bool IsPlaying = false;
    
    public Action OnRoundStart;
    public Action OnRoundEnd;
    public Action<BaseUnit> OnUnitDied;

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " starting");
        PopulateTeam(teamOne, teamOneTag);
        PopulateTeam(teamTwo, teamTwoTag);

        StartCoroutine(WaitForAllObjectsToBeReady());
    }

    private bool UnitsAreReady() {
        foreach (BaseUnit unit in teamOne) {
            if (!unit.IsReady) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        foreach (BaseUnit unit in teamTwo) {
            if (!unit.IsReady) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForAllObjectsToBeReady()
    {
        while (!UnitsAreReady()) {
            Debug.Log("Waiting for 0.5 seconds.");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }
        Debug.Log("Invoking OnRoundStart.");
        OnRoundStart?.Invoke();
    }

    public void UnitDead(BaseUnit unit) {
        teamOne.Remove(unit);
        teamTwo.Remove(unit);

        Debug.Log("Deleting " + unit.gameObject.name);

        OnUnitDied?.Invoke(unit);

        Destroy(unit.gameObject);
    }

    private void PopulateTeam(List<BaseUnit> team, string tag) {
        var teamUnits = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tag);
        foreach (var unit in teamUnits) {
            team.Add(unit.GetComponent<BaseUnit>());
        }
    }

    public List<BaseUnit> GetUnitsAgainst(Team against) {
        return against == Team.Team1
            ? teamTwo : teamOne;
    }
}
```

Any input on how to properly handle this type of thing so there is some variability with which team might win?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try add 3 or 4 teams to see what happens. I'm still reading the code (you could add some comments for yourself and anyone else if your team grows or you have issues) but if you can do some fault finding like this maybe you can work out what's going on.

If you do add 4 teams and the turn order is 4,3,2,1 then I would assume the units are being initialised in ascending order, then calling the WaitForAllObjectsToBeReady() coroutine and the order coming back from that is reveresed (because 1 calls it first, then 2, then 3 then 4 and once 4 is ready it is at the top of the list being the most recent to ready)?

Comment: I didn’t add any additional teams but I did increase it to 3 units per team. It seems that Team2 is always hitting first still though. Depending on placement it’s possible for Team1 to win sometimes, but if all should be even Team2 always wins.